# Tikz have rotated my children nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest

I am drawing a tree in tikz, however, it seems like the children nodes have been rotated, such that the line going into them are offset and passes through. See e.g. this picture. Especially notice the how the lines are off centre and how it passes through the blue ball. [image].

I have drawn the picture using:

```
\includepackage{tikz}
\tikzstyle planar forest=[scale=1, sibling distance=0, level distance=0, semithick]
\tikzstyle planar forest node=[scale=1, shape=circle, semithick, draw]
\tikzstyle b=[style=planar forest node, fill=black]
\tikzstyle bb=[style=planar forest node, fill=blue]
```

to define the environment and:

```
\tikz[planar forest] {
\node [b, label=right:] at (0.0, 0.0) {}
child {node [bb, label=right:] at (-0.5, 1.0) {}
}
child {node [b, label=right:] at (0.5, 1.0) {}
}
;
```

}

to draw the actual figure. Does anyone have an idea why it looks so ugly?

Comment: I don't get the same picture. Here the tree grows upwards with the same attachment points to the nodes, which then becomes correct. Can you combine your code parts and complement to a compilable MWE.

Comment: This doesn't appear to have anything to do with `forest` at all. What does `\includepackage{}` do?

Comment: I get the same as @StefanH when I create an MWE and remove the undefined `\includepackage`.

Answer (score 4):

The basic issue as far as I can tell is that you are mixing a tree structure with manual placement of all nodes. So, if I had to hazard a guess, I would guess that in ***your*** code --- the code which reproduces the problem as opposed to the code you've shared, which doesn't --- you are telling Ti*k*Z that the tree is growing in one direction while manually forcing the location of nodes as if it were growing in another.

It makes no sense to use a tree and then set both `sibling distance` and `level distance` to zero. At least, I may simply lack imagination, but I can't think of a good reason you'd want to do this.

Here's a version of your tree, updated to remove the deprecated `\tikzstyle` and modified to actually be a tree.

```
\tikzset{
  planar forest node/.style={shape=circle, semithick, draw},
  b/.style={style=planar forest node, fill=black},
  bb/.style={style=planar forest node, fill=blue},
}
\tikz {
  \node [b, label=right:A] {}
  child {node [bb, label=right:B]  {}
  }
  child {node [b, label=right:C]  {}
  }
  ;
}
```

[image: tree]

Or, with `grow=up`:

[image: up tree]

If I try hard, I can produce an approximation of your output.

[image: ugly tree]

But I got this by both zeroing `level` and `sibling distance` and setting `yscale=-.75`:

```
\tikz [sibling distance=0, level distance=0, yscale=-.75] {
  \node [b] {}
  child {node [bb] at (-.5,1)  {}
  }
  child {node [b] at (.5,1) {}
  }
  ;
}
```

which is hardly an obvious thing to do.

For completeness, here's a `forest`:

```
\begin{forest}
  [, b
    [, bb
    ]
    [, b
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
```

which produces a tree from a much more concise specification.

[image: forest]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt,multi]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
  planar forest node/.style={shape=circle, semithick, draw},
  b/.style={style=planar forest node, fill=black},
  bb/.style={style=planar forest node, fill=blue},
}
\tikz {
  \node [b, label=right:A] {}
  child {node [bb, label=right:B]  {}
  }
  child {node [b, label=right:C]  {}
  }
  ;
}
\tikz [grow=up] {
  \node [b, label=right:A] {}
  child {node [bb, label=right:B]  {}
  }
  child {node [b, label=right:C]  {}
  }
  ;
}
\tikz [sibling distance=0, level distance=0, yscale=-.75] {
  \node [b] {}
  child {node [bb] at (-.5,1)  {}
  }
  child {node [b] at (.5,1) {}
  }
  ;
}
\begin{forest}
  [, b
    [, bb
    ]
    [, b
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Even my attempt to recreate it fails to get every aspect of whatever is screwed up. This gets the squatness and the angles from the parent, but not the changed anchors of the children (or what looks like that).